# Getting this sql query right with counting and grouping

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having trouble trying to get this query right.

Say I have a table with the following data:

```
id    |   xyz     |   code
===========================
1     |    1      |    ba
2     |    1      |    zz
3     |    1      |    ba
1     |    1      |    zz
1     |    1      |    ba
2     |    1      |    zz
```

And I'd like to get a sum of 'xyz', grouped by id e.g.

```
SELECT id, SUM(xyz) as mysum FROM table WHERE xyz=1 GROUP BY id
```

I would end up with the results:

```
id   |  mysum 
================
1    |  3
2    |  2
3    |  1
```

Perfect.

The thing is, what I'd actually like to do is group by the 'code' column as well, so that if say for id: 1, which has 2 entries with the code 'ba', then the result would be more like this:

```
id   |  mysum 
================
1    |  2
2    |  1
3    |  1
```

Here is where my limited understanding of mysql fails me. Because I would think to do a query like this:

```
SELECT id, SUM(xyz) AS mysum FROM table WHERE xyz=1 GROUP BY id, code
```

But this clearly gives the results I'm *not* after.

How can I do this sort of query that does a SUM of column xyz, while omitting it if it has already added one that has the same 'code'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT id,
       SUM(CASE WHEN code = 'ba' then 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM table1
GROUP BY id
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ccf58/2)

*follow-up question: why does id=2 has a value of 1, isn't it zero?*

**UPDATE 1**

```
SELECT id,
       count(Distinct code)
FROM table1
GROUP BY id
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ccf58/4)

Comment: Woah. I did not know you could do anything like this! Or that sqlfiddle exists. But what about when I'm not just trying to make sure 'ba' is not duplicated in the results, but any of the 'code' column? I'll update my question to clarify this.

Comment: You are a master! Hats off to you sir!

Comment: I didn't really understand the follow-up question - I just made this table up above - my actual table is far more complex. btw your facebook link I think doesn't work.

Comment: @cosmicbdog the followup question was asked before your update :D hehe nevermind for that. my facebook link works :D

Comment: ahh.. it says it doesn't work when i'm not logged in. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT code,SUM(xyz) FROM table GROUP BY code,xyz
```